# Login Validation in Android

Tags: android

i'm inserting the username, password and e-mail values in the android login page. If the username is not valid, it shows invalid username, but after clicking the button. 
    Actually i want the app to show the message as soon as the wrong username is typed and not after clicking the submit button.

Comment: use textwatcher for this functionality

Comment: This is a horrible idea, you don't want to listen each character being changed, you should instead wait for a few seconds after the user has typed and then validate don't listen to each character...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use TextWatcher....

```
      et1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```